# Как установить статус боту Discord?

Tags: node.js, discord, бот

Недавно начал писать бота для Discord и параллельно изучать Discord.JS.
Постоянно вижу ботов с статусом "Играет в /help" или "Смотрит за N серверов"

---

Так вот, как это сделать на Discord.JS 12.2.0?!

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#activityoptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать метод [`setPresence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence)

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '?';
const token = require('./token.json').token;

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Bot is ready`);
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: 'online',
        activity: {
            type: 'WATCHING',
            name: '/help',
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

играет в "/help":

```
bot.user.setPresence({
    game: {
        name: `Играет в ${prefix}help`,
        type: "PLAYING",
    }
});
```

смотрит за N серверами:

```
    bot.user.setPresence({
        game: {
            name: `${bot.guilds.cache.size} серверов`,
            type: "WATCHING",
        }
    });
});
```